# Is it possible to create web-service where some operations have QUALIFIED elements and others have UNQUALIFIED?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf, jax-ws

Colleagues, situation:
I have a WSDL which I use to generate generate classes using  wsdl2java from CXF and deploy Web services. Web service operations worked fine properly before today. In request each attribute has a prefix (as  I understand it means “qualified”).
Today I decided to add a new operation for “hardcoded” client. A feature of this client is that it requires in the attributes of elements without a prefix (new) in request.
E.g. client works with request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sin="http://my.comp/2010/webservice/Service" xmlns:new="http://www.webservice.namespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sin:AuthData>
         <new:login>121212</new:login>
         <new:password>12121</new:password>
      </sin:AuthData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But didn’t work with:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sin="http://my.comp/2010/webservice/Service" xmlns:new="http://www.webservice.namespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sin:AuthData>
         <login>121212</login>
         <password>12121</password>
      </sin:AuthData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

, where no tag `new` in `login` and `password` elements.

**The questions:**

Is it possible to create web service where some operations have all the elements with prefixes and operations in which the elements do not have a prefix?

How to achieve this: correct WSDL, correct CXF  generated classes or something else?

I tried to correct class `package-info.java` (`elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` -> `elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED`) but in this case all prefixes of all elements are removed.  I will be glad to any advice.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, moving classes, which i want to be without prefix (unqualified), to another package helps.